# How to use a variable or a function name to be a place holder for a object's properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

Is there any easy way in JavaScript to use a variable or a function name as a property of a object like this:

```js
var someObject = {
 piece1: 'one',
 piece2: 'two'
};

var trial = "piece1";

alert(someObject[trial]);

function someFunction(secondTrial) {
 return someObject[secondTrail];
};

alert(someFunction(piece1));
```

so that "trial" & "secondTrial" will work as well as "someObjects"'s property; so essentially they would both work like "someObject.piece1"?

Comment: Also note the typo in `someObject[secondTrail]`. I don't understand what you mean by *"[...] use [...] a function name as a property of a object"*

Answer (score 2):

When you do `someFunction(piece1)`, `piece1` will be treated as a variable and since it is not defined yet, `ReferenceError: piece1 is not defined` will be thrown. You need to pass that as a string, like this

```
alert(someFunction("piece1"));
```